# I keep getting "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." in the <option> list

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've tried adding different values to the key attribute , even with Math.random() but seems I'm not getting it right.
I've read that you should also try adding the key to the outer element but in this case... I dk which one is the outer one.

I'm kinda lost. ThANKS!

Here's the code that is offended:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserType from './types/UserType';
import UsersTable from './components/UsersTable';
import getUsers from './services/UserService';
import { Profile, profileValues } from './types/ProfileEnum';

const App = () => {
    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([] as UserType[]);
    const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([] as UserType[]);
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
    const [dateFrom, setDateFrom] = useState();
    const [dateTo, setDateTo] = useState();
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleUsers = async () => {
            const data = await getUsers();

            setAllUsers(data);
        };
        handleUsers();
    }, []);

    let profiles = profileValues.map((profile: Profile, j) => {
        return <option key={j} value={profile}>{profile}</option>;
    });
    profiles.push(<option value=''></option>);

    const handleFilterUsers = () => {
        let filtered = allUsers;

        if (profile) {
            filtered = allUsers.filter(u => u.profile === profile);
        }

        if (fullName) {
            filtered = filtered.filter(u =>
                u.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(fullName.toLowerCase())
            );
        }

        if (dateFrom) {
            filtered = filtered.filter(u => u.birthday >= new Date(dateFrom));
        }

        if (dateTo) {
            filtered = filtered.filter(u => u.birthday <= new Date(dateTo));
        }

        setSelectedUsers(filtered);
    };

    return (
        <div className='page-container'>
            <header>
                <h1>Users List</h1>
                <form
                    onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        handleFilterUsers();
                    }}
                >
                    <div id='filters'>
                        <div className='item'>
                            <label>Full Name</label>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                value={fullName}
                                id='fullname'
                                name='fullname'
                                onChange={(e: any) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='item'>
                            <label>Birtday From</label>
                            <input
                                type='date'
                                value={dateFrom}
                                onChange={(e: any) => setDateFrom(e.target.value)}
                                id='fullname'
                                name='fullname'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='item'>
                            <label>Birthday To</label>
                            <input
                                type='date'
                                value={dateTo}
                                onChange={(e: any) => setDateTo(e.target.value)}
                                id='fullname'
                                name='fullname'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className='item'>
                            <label>Profile</label>
                            <select
                                
                                value={profile}
                                id='profile'
                                name='profile'
                                onChange={(e: any) => setProfile(e.target.value)}
                            >
                                {profiles}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className='item'>
                            <button type='submit' value='Submit'>
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <UsersTable users={selectedUsers} />
                </form>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

here's the Enum I'm importing

```
enum Profile {
    Administrator = 'Administrator',
    Operator = 'Operator',
    Customer = 'Customer',
}

const profileValues = [
    Profile.Administrator,
    Profile.Operator,
    Profile.Customer,
];

export { profileValues, Profile };
```

Comment: I'm looking at this and maybe it's because of  this one? profiles.push(<option value=''></option>); what happens if you give it a random key

Comment: This is not the offended coded. The mentioned warning arise from the use of `map` function, that's the code you should post

Comment: That totally solved my problem. Thanks!!!! Love having other eyes to see my dumb code! haha

Comment: u Right! Will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
<select
   value={profile}
   id='profile'
   name='profile'
   onChange={(e: any) => setProfile(e.target.value)}
   >
       <option value=''>Select a profile</option>
       {profileValues.map((profile: Profile, j) =>
           <option key={j} value={profile}>{profile</option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: Happy to help!. If it helps you would you consider mark the answer as accepted? That would be appreciated